# Modify account expiry date based on data from Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, active-directory

I need to modify the expiry date on Active Directory user accounts, taking the account name and date to set from data that is in Excel.

I have the below VBScript to set an AD expiry date, but I can't work out how to change it so that it takes the account name and date to set as the expiry from particular cells in Excel.

The aim is to provide easy bulk administration of this task that we have to do daily.

```
Set objUser = GetObject _
  ("LDAP://cn=Joe.Bloggs,ou=Management,dc=AN,dc=Franz,dc=com")

objUser.AccountExpirationDate = "10/30/2014"
objUser.SetInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code requires a distinguished name, so you need to resolve the account name to the user object's distinguished name:

```
acct = "..."   'account name

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")

base   = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext") & ">"
filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" _
         & acct & "))"
attr   = "distinguishedName"
scope  = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  dn = rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop

WScript.Echo dn
```

Since AD queries require quite a bit of boilerplate code, and I got tired of having to write it over and over again, I wrapped it in a reusable VBScript class ([`ADQuery`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml)). With this class you can simplify the query to the following:

```
'<-- copy/paste class code here

acct = "..."   'account name

Set qry = New ADQuery
qry.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" _
             & acct & "))"

Set rs = qry.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  dn = rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop

WScript.Echo dn
```

Replace the distinguished name in the code you copied from [ActiveXperts](http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/users/#ConfigExpDate.htm) with the variable `dn`:

```
objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & dn)
objUser.AccountExpirationDate = "10/30/2014"
objUser.SetInfo
```

The account names can be read from an Excel sheet with something like this (provided you have Excel installed):

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xlsx")
Set range = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange

For i = range.Rows(1).Row To range.Rows(range.Rows.Count).Row
  acct = range.Cells(i, 1).Value
  'rest of your code here
Next

wb.Close
xl.Quit
```